# google chart mouse over on x-axis values coming behind div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Added image:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC0X2.png
```

aspx code:

```
 {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt = data1;

            // ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Control);
            List<DataItem> dataList = new List<DataItem>();
            dataList.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                float F1 = float.Parse(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float S1 = float.Parse(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                dataList.Add(new DataItem(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(), F1 / 100, S1 / 100));
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "BodyOnLoadScript11122",
            string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">drawVisualization2({0},{1},{2});</script>", jss.Serialize(dataList),850,800), false);
            jss.Serialize(dataList);

        }
```

java script code:

```
    function drawVisualization2(dataValues,val1,val2) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Class Average');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Child Score');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value1, dataValues[i].Value2]);
        }

        var options = {
            title: 'Competency Performance',
            width: val2,
            height: val1,
            hAxis: { title: 'Competency', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red', fontSize: 15 }, format: '###.#%', textStyle: { fontSize: 12 }
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: "25%" },
            vAxis: { textStyle: { fontSize: 12 }
            }
        };


        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '###.#%' });
        formatter.format(data, 1);
        formatter.format(data, 2);


        new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization2')).
            draw(data, options);
    }


</script>
```

Html code:

```
 <tr>
                <td class="style1" valign="top" align="center">
                    <div style="overflow:auto; width: 815px; height: 415px;" >
                    <div id="visualization2" style=" background-color:#E7E6E6;"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
```

This is complete code.I am not able to find the problem.google chart mouse over on x-axis values  coming behind div.anyone help me to resolve the error.Thank you                ......................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Do you have any CSS that could be affecting the chart or any of its parent elements in the DOM?

Comment: No.i dint use any css style

Comment: Hmm...that kind of problem is usually caused by something in CSS interfering with the layout of the chart.  What version of the API are you loading?

Comment: google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['corechart'] });

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. You can remove center alignment for the div as follows:

   > td class="style1" valign="top" align="left"
2. Or, you can hold the center alignment and add this:

   > td class="style1" valign="top" align="center" style='display: inline-block'